# How can I transfer nonstationary data to stationary data for ARIMA?

Tags: data-transformation

I want to do ARIMA in SAS, but the data is nonstationary. Are there any ways to transfer nonstationary data to stationary data? Are there any tools in SAS for transfering nonstationary data to stationary data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a programming site, so answers are generally given only in a more general statistical sense, and, I would recommend changing the question to prevent it from being deleted as off-topic. It is also difficult to answer your question because the type of nonstationarity is unspecified. ARIMA is already a correction for nonstationarity. The type of nonstationarity is then by implication not ARIMA type.

So, it depends if there is a useful inverse transform for the non-
ARIMA nonstationarity or not. In general, that depends on what that non-stationary is, exactly, so more information is needed to more specifically address the question.